# Prisma trying to create object but object type is not assignable to type never

Tags: typescript, prisma

My schema is as follows:

```
model Course {
    id               String             @id @default(cuid())
    courseName       String
    modules Module[]
}

model ActivityResource {
    id   String @id @unique
    type type
    name String
    url  String
    relation Module @relation(fields: [id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model Module {
    id String @id @default(cuid())
    moduleName String
    order            Int
    ActivityResource ActivityResource[]
    relation Course @relation(fields: [id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

enum type {
    EXAMPLE
    CHALLENGE
    CODING
}
```

Im trying to create some dummy data in my db.

Ive tried to make a mock course but typescript gives me the following error:

`Type '{ moduleName: string; order: number; ActivityResource: { create: { type: { set: string[]; }; name: string; url: string; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

```js
const java = await prisma.course.create({
    data: {
      courseName: "java",
      modules: {
        create: [
          {
            moduleName: "Encapsulation",
            order: 1,
            ActivityResource: {
                create: [{
                    type: {set: ['EXAMPLE']},
                    name: "ActivityName",
                    url: "someurl",
                }]
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
}
```

I feel like some arbitrary misconception is bugging me here. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

it was all along how the enum was set. Should not be `{set: ['EXAMPLE']},` but import the enum from prisma client and set the enum as `type.EXAMPLE`